# parse to child element of nested JSON using python

Tags: python, json

Suppose our JSON file has data:

```
[{
"key1": "value",
"key2": [{
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": [{
                "key1": "value",
                "key2": "value"
            }]              
    },
    {
        "key1": "value",
        "key2": "value"
    }]
}]
```

In this case, I can access the child using:

```
with open (filename) as f:
     data = json.load(f)

data[0]['key2'][0]['key2']
```

But how can I access child element if I dont know how many times it is nested? Is there a way to generate pattern like `data[0]['key2'][0]['key2'][0]['key2'][0]['key2']` or a better way of accessing child.

PS: After accessing child element I would need to modify it and then save it in the same source file.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with a full solution right now, but have you tried using a try, except block, you can keep going deeper till you hit an exception and that will tell you when to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way I can think is
with a recursive function

```
def recursive(json):
    for value in json:
        # value condition
        if str(value):
            print(value)
            break
        else:
            recursive(value)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It might help you [https://linuxhint.com/python-dictionary-length/#:~:text=Using%20the%20built%2Din%20function,by%20the%20len()%20function](https://linuxhint.com/python-dictionary-length/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20built%2Din%20function,by%20the%20len()%20function).

or you can use the nested loops and calculate the length of the upcoming key

```py
for x in fruits:
    print(x)
    for y in x:
        print(y)
        len(y)....
```